# Overllaping view elements

Tags: android

Here's the problem I'm facing : I've got a custom slider that controlls the volume and a label "volume" that I combine together in a liniar Layout to obtain a volume control setting. In the emulator and on a G1 phone these look pretty ok , however , when put on a Xperia mini 
the label and the slider overlap . What should I do obtain a decent view independent of the device the application runs ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a relative layout instead. It should be pretty easy to switch, and it should prevent the overlapping.